# Parametrizing projective cubics

Tags: algebraic-geometry

(EDIT: I’ve updated this question to feature a new cubic. Sorry for asking so many similar questions. The responses that I’ve received so far have been extremely helpful.)

> Consider a cubic in $P^2(\mathbb{C})$ defined by a conic and its tangent. Write a parametrization $\gamma(t)$ such that $t=\infty$ corresponds to the unique singular point, and the sum of the parameters of three collinear points is equal to 0.

I think this problem is related to a question that I posted recently: [Unique group law on cubic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4883933/unique-group-law-on-cubic/4885030#4885030)

I’d like to work with the cubic $F(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2-z^2)(x-z)$. But I can’t see how to parametrize this curve in $P^2(\mathbb{C})$. I think something like $\gamma(t)=[t^2-1:-2t: t^2+1]$ should parametrize the conic, but I’m not sure how to get the tangent line as well… It seems I’d need more parameters.

I calculated the singular point of this cubic to be $[1: 0: 1]$, which $\gamma(t)$ approaches as $t$ goes to infinity. Am I on to something here?

Comment: You keep saying projective curve, so you answered your question. Your parametrization $[1/t^3,1/t^2,1] = [1,t,t^3]$ is correct. Now work out the condition for points with parameters $s,t,u$ to be collinear.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've updated the question.

Comment: You should not change the question in the middle of discussion. Regarding the new question, "and its tangent" does not make much sense. Do you mean the tangent *line* at some particular point? And you keep confusing dimensions: It's a *curve* in $\Bbb P^2$ and a tangent *line*. The rational parametrization of a conic is not going to help you parametrize this singular cubic. Think about how you parametrized a singular cubic in the previous cases. At what point is the line you took tangent to the conic?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how the problem was worded to me. The "tangent line at some particular point" is my interpretation.

Comment: That's more accurate than saying "its tangent." At any rate, you have a smooth conic. At what point is its tangent line the line $x-z=0$?

Comment: That would be the point [1 : 0 : 1]. Am I looking for a trigonometric parametrization?

Comment: No. You should proceed as in the other cases, looking at the pencil of lines through the singular point.

Comment: Sorry - I thought I had the idea, but I'm still not understanding. The pencil of lines through the singular point gives me a parametrization of the conic, but I'm not seeing how to parametrize the whole cubic using a single parameter. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: I spoke too quickly. A reducible curve such as this cannot be rationally parametrized.